# cakephp : save All condition

Tags: cakephp

I have userdetails table and user table  where user has many userdetails ,& userdetails belongs to user.

on userdetails/add  i want the cost column under user table to be saved on userdetails/add->submit.

in my userdetails/add form i have $this->Userdetail->input(User.cost);

in my controller userdetails -> add  i am using saveall .

now when i add a new user detail ,a user detail record is created and in user table a new record is created with cost column filled what i entered in userdetail add form,
what i want is cost in user column should not be added as a new record,it should be saved or updated with the user i have logged in .

i want to know how to pass condition in saveall so that when i add a user detail the cost column in user is saved but in front of the logged in user not a newly created record in user.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is set the User ID to the ID of the logged in user, before saving. If the ID isn't set it creates a new record, so to edit an existing record it has to be set.

Try this before saving:

```
$this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');
```